# creating k8s secret results in public private key not matching

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate, amazon-eks, amazon-acm

I have created a certificate using ACM. Now, I want to create a TLS secret using kubernetes, so that I can use the secret to configure Ingress Resource.

I am trying to create a TLS secret using `kubectl create secret tls fsi-secret --cert=fsi.chain.pem --key=fsi.key.pem`  *However, it returns an error saying `error: failed to load key pair tls: failed to parse private key`*

The private key was created using a password, so after reading through a bit, I decided to use the unencrypted private key, so I did the following:

```
openssl rsa -in fsi.key.pem -out fsi.key.decrypted.pem -passin pass: abcdefgxxxx
```

The above step generated an unencrypted version of the original private key.
Next I tried the `create secret` command above just changing the --key to use the unencrypted key:

```
kubectl create secret tls fsi-secret --cert=fsi.chain.pem --key=fsi.key.decrypted.pem
```

however, this resulted in `error: failed to load key pair tls: private key does not match public key`.

I am creating this tls secret in order to use it in the ingress resource definition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Cricket and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you share the chain order of the cert that you have created?

Answer (score 2):

The one thing you should check is the chain order of your certificate as the first certificate will be checked against the private key. So, having your cert like this:

```
-----BEGIN MY CERTIFICATE-----
-----END MY CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
-----END INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
-----END INTERMEDIATE CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN ROOT CERTIFICATE-----
-----END ROOT CERTIFICATE-----
```

will make sure the order is right.

You can find more in-depth sources regarding that topic below:

- [Write an example using interemediate certs and Ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24669)
- [Get your certificate chain right](https://medium.com/@superseb/get-your-certificate-chain-right-4b117a9c0fce)

If that's still not the case, please let us know and update your question.

Comment: Hello @Cricket and welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this issue when creating a Kubernetes secret from a rooot certificate and an intermediate certificate.

The issue was a error with my concatenated certificate file.

I used the command below to concatenate the root certificate and the intermediate certificate:

```
cat root-certificate.crt intermediate-certificate.pem > bundled-certificate.crt
```

When I ran the command below to generate the secret:

```
kubectl create secret tls myapp-tls --key=my-cert-private.key --cert=bundled-certificate.crt --namespace production --dry-run=client -o yaml > myapp_bundle_cert.yaml
```

I get the error:

```
error: tls: private key does not match public key
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

When I checked the concatenated certificate file. I found that there was an overlap that looked like this:

```
-----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

All I had to do was to fix the formatting:

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

Afterwhich, when I ran the command:

```
kubectl create secret tls myapp-tls --key=my-cert-private.key --cert=bundled-certificate.crt --namespace production --dry-run=client -o yaml > myapp_bundle_cert.yaml
```

It worked fine.